# I can't get list of dynamoDB tables from localstack running with docker

Tags: docker, localstack

I installed localstack and awscli within a docker container.
I run different aws commands to list streams and buckets but when I tried to list dynamoDB tables (as below), it failed :

```
aws --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4569 dynamodb list-tables
```

Here is the error I get :

```
2018-07-12T09:26:35:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4564): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f68941a43d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 201, in forward
    headers=forward_headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508,in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618,in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508,in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4564): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f68941a43d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I did not find on internet any response that solved my problem.

If anyone has a clue or an idea, I will be thankful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you are running localstack, and connecting to it?  It would seem this is a networking issue, which can get a bit complicated when using various docker configurations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to view your Dynamo DB on localstack, you can install Commandeer, which gives you a UI for both local and AWS.  https://getcommandeer.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, you can use the `jar` library for simulate some amazon components:

In first instance you need to add the following component in your `pom.xml` in order to be able to initialize the localstack directly during the test:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>cloud.localstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>localstack-utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then, you need to specify the following library if you need to use dynamo  <s>cause the latest one proivded from `aws` are not compliant with the latest version of localstack:</s>

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.721</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now you can use the following annotations in order to instantiate the stack using docker, the images will be pulled automatically if not present in the system. So no is not necessary to run any docker/docker-compose image.

```java
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb"})
@ExtendWith(LocalstackDockerExtension.class)
@Slf4j
public class TestPipelineComplete {

public static final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "foo";
public static final String AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "bar";
    static {
        System.setProperty("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
        System.setProperty("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    }
}
```

Now, if you need to initialize a `DynamoDB` client you can use the following line:

```java
final AmazonDynamoDB clientDynamoDB = cloud.localstack.TestUtils.getClientDynamoDB();
```